# API Response JSON to Class Object in Java

Tags: java, json, api, transform

I am getting a service response from Azure API in JSON format, but I need to transform it into Java class object format. Please suggest the simplest way to transform

Comment: There are plenty of way how to transform it but most importantly have you done any research so far on how to do it? I suggest you present your findings before you seek for general answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is website on which you can put json response and select the language in which you want to create classes.
This is simplest way to transform -

https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Exemple  :

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        UserType user= mapper.readValue("your_Json", UserType.class);
```